# Grayscale image with CSS on Safari 5.x

Tags: css, safari, grayscale

I am trying to show some images on a page where they should be shown in **grayscale, except on mouse hover  when they smoothly transition into color**. I've made it work nicely on IE, Chrome and Firefox, but it **doesn't work on Safari 5.x**. The problem is on Safari for Mac *and* Safari for Windows. Here is the code I have so far:

```
filter: url('desaturate.svg#greyscale'); 
filter: gray;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
```

The first line loads an external .svg filter (I don't inline it with a `url("data:`... rule because I want to avoid [a bug in old versions of Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852095/svg-filters-in-firefox/6345950#comment16869365_6345950)).

The second line is for IE and seems to work just as well as `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1);`.

The last line about webkit is supposed to work on Safari 6 and above, as well as Chrome.

Is there any CSS rule to show the images with grayscale on **Safari 5.x**? Or, if that is not possible, can someone recommend a javascript solution, preferably one that will handle the animation to and from grayscale? **I would like to avoid a server-side hack** with grayscale images because that will mess up my HTML and then I'll have to do some nasty browser detection to serve HTML conditionally.

thanks

**Edit:**

*As this has turned out to be a "notable question", please don't keep posting here more answers that only work on Safari 6 and above, or answers that include an .svg file in a data url. At the time when I wrote the OP, it was important for me to support some versions of Safari and Firefox that are today considered **very** dated, but nevertheless that was my original question.*

***I am well aware that for modern browsers grayscale filtering is easily accomplished with a few lines of CSS code**, but the graphics designer was using Safari 5.x and the client was using Firefox 3.x at the time I did this project. The solution that worked for me was what Giona suggested, i.e. to use Modernizr to test for css-filtering, and if it's not supported to fall back to javascript.*

*If I was doing the same thing today, I'd be telling both to go update their browsers!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css-filters) , CSS3 filters are supported by very few browsers at the moment.

There are many JavaScript/jQuery fallback if you Google "[javascript grayscale plugin](http://www.google.it/search?q=jquery%20grayscale%20plugin)".
Here are some:

- [Grayscale.js](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/)
- [jQuery GreyScale plugin](https://github.com/Prydie/jQuery-GreyScale-Plugin)
- [Hoverizr](http://www.iliasiovis.com/hoverizr/)
- [Do it with canvas (tutorial)](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html)

But i've no experience with them, so i can't suggest you which one is the best.

I tried [jQuery Black And White](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jQuery.BlackAndWhite) long time ago, and it gave me a lot of issues with relative/absolute positioned images, so maybe avoid it.

---

Including this [Modernizr build](http://modernizr.com/download/#-shiv-cssclasses-css_filters-load) into your pages, you can target browser not supporting filters via Javascript:

```
if(!Modernizr.css_filters){
    /* javascript fallback here */
}
```

or CSS:

```
.no-css_filters .element {
    /* css fallback here */
}
```

---

Oh, and don't forget [dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser?](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

Comment: Hey man thanks for the links. Later I'll look at them and see which one does the trick for me, and I'll report back here. Hoverizr looks promising. Also, I like the idea of using Modernizr for this, so thanks for that too. As for your last point, I agree, but try telling that to my client and graphics designer. *sigh*

Comment: Eheheh i know, clients and photoshop maniacs can't understand. Modernizr is one of the most useful tool for web designers, you can also easily [add custom tests](http://modernizr.com/docs/#testallprops)! Good coding @alexg

Comment: I finally got around to do this. Turns out I used Grayscale.js. Your second and third links are the same project, and it had some bug where it assumes (line 82 in the source code) that images are <img src=""> while mine were background-images. Also, the correct link for the modernizr build is http://modernizr.com/download/#-shiv-cssclasses-prefixes-css_filters-load because you also need the _prefixes to test for css filters. Now it should work on Safari 3.1 and above, according to http://caniuse.com/canvas. I didn't get the animation working but I think it's fine the way it is.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I used Safari 5.0.3 for windows to test it.

Comment: *sidenote*: jQuery GreyScale plugin does not work in Chrome 24 due to cross-domain security issues.

Comment: For those who also had errors, it's not ``Modernizr.css_filters``, but rather, it's ``Modernizr.cssfilters``.  Also note, you may need to either download a custom build with CSS filter detection or load in the test located at ``feature-detects/css-filters.js`` on the repository.

Comment: For anyone looking how to use these methods with the google maps, please take a look at Google Maps JavaScript API v3 - Styled maps.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple, actually:

- http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html
- http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/487/

I tried using the javascript fallback, but it really made no sense, and it was really slow on large images.  This made a lot more sense.  Note that there is a new syntax for `grayscale`, and I had to manually edit the resulting minified CSS from LESS.

Here's my mixin:

```
.filter (...) {
    -webkit-filter: @arguments;
    -moz-filter: @arguments;
    -ms-filter: @arguments;
    -o-filter: @arguments;
    filter: @arguments;
}
```

And my class:

```
.grayscale-hover, .home-image {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android see http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/487/*/
    .filter(grayscale(1) blur(1px));
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
    &:hover {
        .filter(none);
        filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    }
}
```

Works and tested in IE 6+, Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: Hey, thanks. +1 for the thorough work, but does it work in Safari 5.1 as I asked in my OP? I don't have access to that browser right now. And as I also mentioned in the OP, inlining an svg filter using a `data:` url doesn't work in some old versions of FF (e.g. 4.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

This is something like that:

```
.grayscale {    
   filter: url(css/grayscale.svg#greyscale);    
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);    
   -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);    
   -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);    
   -o-filter: grayscale(100%);    
}
```

You need to download the svg file either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. I am removing your link so that no one flags this as spam.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked great for me:

---

```
img { float:left;
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\' filterRes=\'800\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
         -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
            transition: all 1.5s ease;
            z-index: 40 !important;
             display:block;

 }

img:hover { 
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\' filterRes=\'800\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);}
```

---

The images looks really overexposed in Safari however (But they are in greyscale). And the transition isn't supported by Firefox.