# Present html page in greyscale

Tags: javascript, grayscale

I am looking for the simplest way to make my page appear in greyscale.

I have found plugin (http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/), but it has some cons, eg. it doesnt handle background images well.

Do you know any alternatives or updates to this tool?

Answer (score 1):

You could try working with a filter:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/

but this might not work on all browsers, certainly doesn't work on old ones.

Comment: True, old browsers are an issue. The full picture is here http://caniuse.com/css-filters

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cross-browser solution, you'll probably have to rely on javascript

Here's some solutions that [I got as answer to one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12685978/1223744):

- [Grayscale.js](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/)
- [jQuery GreyScale plugin](https://github.com/Prydie/jQuery-GreyScale-Plugin)
- [Hoverizr](http://www.iliasiovis.com/hoverizr/)
- [Do it with canvas (tutorial)](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html)

I have used *Grayscale.js* and it worked ok for me but you could try the other three.