# Filter grayscale doesn't work on mobile safari

Tags: css, grayscale

I got a PNG which I want to invert into white

This snippet works on all browsers i've testet but not on an iPhone

```
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) brightness(200%);
    filter: grayscale(1);
```

Does anyone know a fix for that?

Comment: filter is over-riding -webkit-filter on iOS, but you don't have the invert or brightness in it.

Comment: try to change the order of properties.

Comment: The [filter property should work fine for mobile iOS browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter). Can you make a [js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the code in question? If its an older iPhone safari version (5.x) you can [read some solutions to this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685794/grayscale-image-with-css-on-safari-5-x).