# CSS filter is very slow on Safari with different order, can someone explain?

Tags: css, safari, css-filters

Seems like the position/order of the `filter: none;` make a huge difference in Safari (speed). Could some one provide a solid explaination of what happening?

**Check the following two example in Safari only**

---

*Example 1: (With `filter: none;` at the end of CSS rule it is very slow on Safari)*

#### [Example 1 (Slow on safari)](https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/dcnqasdv/)

```
section#pitches>div>div:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: none; /* IE 6-9 */
}
```

---

*Example 2: (Move `filter: none;` above other browser specific filter make it much much faster)*

#### [Example 2 (Much faster)](https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/L7a1mj6t/)

```
section#pitches>div>div:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: none; /* IE 6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

I searched online try to find an explanation but no luck?

I have my guesses but as far as I know CSS does not STOP checking other rules if seen like `filter: none;`?

Comment: Tell me how this work on Safari: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwPWzP

Comment: I also deleted my answer temporary, as I want to know how the above worked in Safari. As I wrote in a comment, the _hover_ rule using `filter: none` is most likely not the issue, it is the `filter: gray` that causes this on Safari

Comment: @LGSon the codepen you posted, it is really slow on Safari, basically same to Example 1.

Comment: Okay, and how does this one work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ogmagz

Comment: Btw, here is another post about a Safari filter issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685794/grayscale-image-with-css-on-safari-5-x

Comment: Unrelated but why do you have so many prefixes there? -moz-filter and -o-filter don't even exist, and -ms-filter is a different kind of filter that has no relation to the standard making -ms-filter: grayscale(0%) equally meaningless.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, you are right, updated. Just curious about how safari treat those css different thank chrome/firefox, hope someone might know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main issue is the way you are implementing your `filter: none;` (or, the way you are removing the previously-set grayscale filter). You are right to say that:

> as far as I know CSS does not STOP checking other rules if seen like
>   filter: none;?

but that is precisely the issue! It seems setting the filter to none is a lot more resource-intensive than simply changing the grayscale back to `0%`!

I found a quote in the book *Pro CSS3 Animation* by Dudley Storey that corroborates this hypothesis:

"Note that you cannot transition smoothly to a state of 'none' or no filter applied; the filter must be given a fresh value" ([Storey, 113](https://books.google.com/books?id=s2VM6v7UK0kC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=filter:none;%20versus%20grayscale(0%25)&source=bl&ots=_DjE4NESfu&sig=OBMyN_KtIIrW7-HivUg0eUwVYpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQs_GD04XVAhWBvBQKHVBCAPIQ6AEIVjAH#v=onepage&q=transition%20smoothly%20to%20a%20state%20of%20%E2%80%9Cnone%E2%80%9D%20&f=false))

Therefore, in Example 1, Safari is reading the CSS and is essentially being left with the much more labor-intensive feat of removing all filters rather than setting *only* the grayscale filter to `0%`. In Example 2, Safari sees the `-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);` last, which means it is the CSS it executes (and has an easier time doing it).

While I think this answers the question, I hope more experienced people share their input. I'm not really satisfied myself, because I've been told that convention is to put "generic" CSS tags before your own (putting `-webkit`, `-moz`, before other CSS), and the only information I found on Apple Safari Documentation is a vague warning:

> Filters are visual effects that can be applied to images and other
>   HTML elements... These filters are resource-intensive. Use them
>   sparingly and only when necessary. Be sure to test your content on a
>   multitude of computers and devices to assert that rendering
>   performance is not hampered, especially if animating. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/Functions.html)

The easiest (and most compliant with convention, it seems) is to simply remove `filter:none;` entirely, since it is redundant and frankly unnecessary if the only filter you are removing is grayscale.

I hope it helps, and that the answer is coherent. It's a little late for me so forgive me for any errors!

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS property on element with blur

```
transform: translateZ(0)
```

to make CSS render on GPU

Comment: I was really surprised when this made a massive difference to the speed of filters on an old iPhone 6. Just saved my life since I still have a lot of users on those.

How did you know about that trick? Is it documented somewhere?